# Excel file cannot be read by arrays in php

Tags: php, yii2

Sorry for my english) I have a problem! I read file with extension .csv but each line returns string, like this

```
36794;"""Белоснежка""";"9785783314353";"Белоснежка";0;0;""
36795;"""Гуси-лебеди""";"9785783320361";"Гуси-лебеди";1;0;""
```

I can't convert these strings to array. This is my code.

```
if (($handle = fopen($local_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                $num = count($data);
                $row++;
                for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                    echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
                }
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
```

This is my file.
[image]

Thank you for your help)))

Comment: Check split (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask no question actually...

But the CSV is quoted properly, at least if the double quotes ought to be correct in the columns B and D.

edit: You're using the wrong delimiter. The file contains semicolon, while you specify colon.